# How to import a local module from other directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, import, module

I made a python module which contains "template" functions i want to use in other classes. My Problem is that VS Code says "unable to import module" ---> ModuleNotFoundError

This is how i import:

```
from utils.util_embeds import Embeds
```

The File is in a subdirectory where the current file is located.

Comment: So you have `src/a.py` and `src/utils/util_embeds.py` and inside `a.py` you what to import it? You have to use relative imports: `from .utils.util_embeds import Embeds` (note the starting dot). But it is unclear whether this is the situation you are in. You should really describe your folder structure.

Comment: Yes its exactly as you guessed i will try it out :) Does the . indicate for subdirectory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

- how files are structured

```
.
├── main.py
└── test2/
    ├── file.py
    └── __init__.py
```

- what files contain

```
# main.py
from test2 import file
file.foo(10)
file.foo(None)

import test2
test2.file.foo(False)
test2.file.foo("hello world!")

from test2.file import foo
foo("Hello there")
```

- This file is crucial, you cannot import directly from a subfolder
  this file has to be a proxy.

```
# __init__.py
from . import file

# from . import * this would import everything from the directory
#                 where the file is placed instead of specifying
#                 every file
```

```
# file.py

def foo(x):
    print("x is:", x)
```

Comment: Its works now but my IDE shows this Error Message: Attempted relative import beyond top-level package...what does this mean?